# Ubuntu 16.04 + Cinnamon can't have different language for window

Tags: cinnamon, input-language

There are two languages (at least) installed on my PC - english and russian. I want to have the language be kept after window.

The setting <kbd>Text Entry Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Input Sources</kbd> → <kbd>Options</kbd> → <kbd>Allow different sources for each window</kbd> doesn't work properly for who knows what reason.

What shall I check in system configuration? 
Maybe there is a known bug with that?

Comment: @user3140225 Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1173925/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Thank you for accepting my suggestions! I saw your edit and I have already read the editing help. In addition to the editing help, I also try to follow [these](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines) formatting suggestions. According to these, menu entries should be italicized, that's why I italicized them. I personally think that italics indeed improve menu entries readability. I wouldn't use <kbd> tags for this, since I only use them for keyboard buttons.

Comment: @user3140225 [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311579/275497).  Consistency is the most important thing, so feel free to roll back my edit if it hurts your eyes...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby However, it is perfectly fine that you use them, since every editor has his own preferences and there are no official guidelines for menu entries. Just the editors' personal taste and experience. Since I am relatively new to editing, I try to learn from the edits on my suggestions, such as yours, and from edits  of other users I come across in various posts.

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for this meta post! It's really useful!